# $\text{range}T=W$ if and only if $(\text{range}T)^{\circ}=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

**Notations and Definitions**

- $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the field $\Bbb{F}$.
- $U$ is a subspace of the vector field $V$.
- $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ denotes the vector space of all linear maps $T:V \to W$.
- $V'=\mathcal{L}(V,\Bbb{F})$ denotes the dual space of V.
- $T':W' \to V'$ is the dual map of $T$ defined by $T'(w')=w' \circ T$ where $\circ$ is the composition.
- $U^{\circ}=\{v' \in V': v'(U)=\{0\}\}$ denotes the annihilator of $U$.

---

**Question**

I want to prove that

> **Theorem**. Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Then $\text{range}T=W$ (which is equivalent to $T$ is surjective) if and only if $(\text{range}T)^{\circ}=\{0\}$.

I can prove it in the forward direction. The argument is as follows. By the definition of *annihilator* we know that

$$(\text{range}T)^{\circ}=\{\phi \in \mathcal{L}(W,\Bbb{F}):\phi(\text{range}T)=\{0\}\}$$

so if $\text{range}T=W$ then

$$(\text{range}T)^{\circ}=\{\phi \in \mathcal{L}(W,\Bbb{F}):\phi(W)=\{0\}\}$$

but we know that the zero map $0 \in \mathcal{L}(W,\Bbb{F})$ does this and furthermore since it is the additive identity of the vector space $\mathcal{L}(W,\Bbb{F})$ it is unique. So we can conclude that

$$(\text{range}T)^{\circ}=\{0\}$$

which completes the proof in this direction. However, I am stuck to prove it in the backward direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a finite dimensional vector space $W$, every subspace $E$ of $W$ satisfies

$$(E^{\circ})^{\circ}=E \tag{*}$$

So $((\text{range }T)^{\circ})^{\circ}=(0)^{\circ}=W$ since the zero linear form vanishes at every point of $W$.

See [this pdf file](https://www.math.ku.edu/~mandal/math790/annihilator.pdf) for a proof. In particular, note the identification of $W$ with its double dual. Note also that if $F$ is a subspace of $W'$, then $F^{\circ}$ can also be defined as $\{x\in W : \forall f\in F, f(x)=0\}$ which is **different** from your definition of *annihilator*. In this case, $(E^{\circ})^{\circ} \subseteq W$ so that the equality $(*)$ makes sense. If we defined $F^{\circ}$ as $\{\varphi\in W'' : \forall f\in F, \varphi(f)=0\}$ then the equality $(*)$ would not make sense and we could only have an isomorphism (coming from the isomorphism $W\simeq W''$ for finite dim. vector spaces)

Comment: Yeah thanks. Also please remove these comments. I will remove this comments when I saw yours are removed. :)