# $T \in \mathcal L(V,W)$ is surjective $\iff ($range $T)^0 = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

I need some help proving this statement. I don't really get why the set of functions that map every $v \in V$ to $0 \in W$ has to be empty. Why is this necessary for the map to be surjective? And what's the proof?

(I looked at this question: [$\text{range}T=W$ if and only if $(\text{range}T)^{\circ}=\{0\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888020/textranget-w-if-and-only-if-textranget-circ-0),
but I couldn't understand the given answer.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if $T$ is surjective, then $T(V)=W$ so $(range T)^0=W^0=\{v':v'(W)=\{0\}\}$ i.e. $(range T)^0$ is the set of all the linear functionals on $W$ which takes the entire space $W$ to $\{0\}$ which is obviously only the zero functional. So $(range T)^0=\{0\}.$

Suppose $(rangeT)^0=\{0\}$. If we denote $U=range T$, then $U$ is a subspace of $W$ and $U^0=\{0\}$ implies that the only linear functional that takes $U$ to $\{0\}$ is the zero functional which implies that $U=W$. (If $U$ were properly contained in $W$, then we could construct a nonzero functional that takes $U$ to $\{0\}$.) So $T$ is surjective.